# Cant get my PDF to display image based on dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have a PDF with a dropdown of company addresses. My problem is that I want multiple selections to show the same logo, but different addresses.

The reason for this is that we are technically 2 companies, each with 3 locations.

locations A/B/C show logo #1, with the address varying between each location.

Locations D/E/F show logo #2, with the address varying between each location.

I have a drop-down list on my PDF form with the text descriptions that match the variable names I've set up below. I also have a button for each logo, named "NEIS_button" and "SIS_button"

I have clunked together (and that really is the best description) the code below for the drop-down field under "custom validation":

```
var N1="NEIS - NY"
var N2="NEIS - PA"
var N3="NEIS - RI"

var S1="SIS - OH"
var S2="SIS - GRAND RAPIDS"
var S3="SIS - MIDLAND"


this.getField("NEIS_Button").display = event.value== (N1 || N2 || N3) ? display.visible : display.hidden;

this.getField("SIS_Button").display = event.value== (S1 || S2 || S3) ? display.visible : display.hidden;
```

When I choose the addresses, it will turn on the logo correctly for the first item in each location only. (i.e. N1 or S1 only)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: where is the code of `this.getField`?

Comment: @OrAssayag the code is in the "run custom validation script" property of my dropdown menu. I am using Bluebeam Revu to create the forms.